# Emails from website gotchas

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

I'm working on a website and I need it to send email (address confirmation messages, notifications, etc. No spam or anything shady.). I know how to get the site to contact an smtp server, etc, but I was wondering if there's anything I need to look out for.

Can I just reliably use Gmail for this or do they frown on having their service used for this sort of thing? Will I eventually get blocked if it's used in quantity or is this usually the way to go?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alot of things that can trip you up when sending email, and I wouldn't suggest trying to use Gmail to do so. You need to consider deliverability, email law (CAN-SPAM) and managing subscriptions (unsubscribes).

I would strongly suggest you look into a transactional email service. [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/), [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) and [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/) are 3 of the leading services.